# Создал для инфоблока свойство типа "список", в зависимости от значения свойства не работает If

Tags: битрикс

В инфоблоке "Бренды" задал свойство "подарок для всех товаров", с типом список (не множественное, необязательное, с значением Y -> Да, по умолчанию без значения). В настройках детального просмотра выбрал созданное свойство, в данном случае `'GIFT_FOR_ALL'`. При отображении хотел бы чтобы при включенном свойстве `'GIFT_FOR_ALL'`, у всех товаров отображался лейбл. Для товаров например добавление похожего свойства не вызвало не каких проблем, оно прекрасно выводилось по условию `$arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]['GIFT']`. Но в данном случае подобное не получилось. В конечном счете сделал следующее в шаблоне template.php:

```
       $property_enums = CIBlockPropertyEnum::GetList(Array("SORT"=>"ASC"), Array("IBLOCK_ID"=> 8, "PROPERTY_ID"=>122, ));
                            $gift = '';
                            while($enum_fields = $property_enums->GetNext())
                            {

                                $gift = $enum_fields["VALUE"];
                            }
 <? if($gift == 'Да'):?>
                                <div class="sticker-box-gift" >
                                <span class="sticker-gift">Ручка в подарок</span>
                            </div>
                            <? endif; ?>
```

В итоге выводится всегда "Да". Нужно чтобы выводился лейбл только тогда, когда свойство 'GIFT_FOR_ALL' равно 'Да'. Подскажите пожалуйста как корректно выводить актуальное значение 'GIFT_FOR_ALL' для текущего бренда.
Дополнительно скриншот прикладываю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: $arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]['GIFT_FOR_ALL']['VALUE']  выводит что ни будь ?

Comment: Выводит NULL по var_dumpу

Comment: тогда в компонент в $arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] не приходит свойство GIFT_FOR_ALL или в инфоблоке свойство с таким кодом отсутствует или в настройках детальной страницы компонента не указано свойство.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы подтягиваете значение свойства 'GIFT_FOR_ALL' из другого инфоблока? А что в переменной $gift, print_r($gift) - что возвращает?
Если не принципиально важно задавать свойство в другом инфоблоке, я бы задал свойство 'GIFT_FOR_ALL' в инфоблоке каталога, и получал бы его без дополнительного обращения к базе данных в массиве $arResult.

```html
    <?if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["GIFT_FOR_ALL"]["VALUE"]):?>
     <div class="sticker-box-gift" >
      <span class="sticker-gift">Ручка в подарок</span>
     </div>
    <? endif; ?>
```

В данном случае не пустое значение массива $arResult["PROPERTIES"]["GIFT_FOR_ALL"]["VALUE"] соответствует true, и код под условием if отработает.

Comment: print_r возращает "Да". Мне бы хотелось задавать отображение лейбла именно для конкретного бренда. Прикрепил фото в вопросе для большей наглядности моих действий